Switched from UFW to iptables-persistent. Old rules not visible, but still apply
On a Ubuntu 24.04 system I had three rules in UFW to open TCP ports 22, 80, and 443, all other ports closed for input by default. Then I switched to iptables-persistent, uninstalling UFW in the process. I agreed to the install script prompt to save existing rules in /etc/iptables/rules.v4.
Now I don't see the old rules listed anywhere by the 'iptables-save' command, yet they still work. E.g., I scanned my server ports externally, and only TCP ports 22, 80, and 443 showed up as open. Why would that be and how do I access those old rules for editing?
Note: I didn't yet reboot since installing iptables-persistent.
My iptables-save output:
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [638408:727075544]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.4/24 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 17 15:04:19 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Tue Sep 17 15:04:19 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [427165:399385173]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [213445:327993299]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [399285:703946799]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 17 15:04:19 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Tue Sep 17 15:04:19 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9466:640884]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 17 15:04:19 2024


